# How to make people understand what the default button is on a website?

Tags: browser, website, hotkeys

I'm building a website and people just don't get the default button. They never hit enter, they use their mouse and click.

It's frustrating since I made the button light blue with a surrounding lightblue glow around it.

How do you perceive it when a button is the "enter fires this" button ?

Is there another way I don't know about?

Comment: You may get a better answer for your question at our sister site, [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/). Be sure to check their FAQ and search to see if your question has already been answered there.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks - I was browsing google but couldnt find something apropriate, so I ended here. Can you move the question over there?

Answer (score 1):

> They never hit enter
>
> How do you perceive it when a button is the "enter fires this" button

Seems like a contradiction? If they never hit enter, why bother hi-lighting it as enter fires this button? With all that hi-lighting and glow around your button I bet they are clicking it like mad.

What else do you want them to do?

Comment: Well no it's not a contradiction. I want them to buy a pony for the backyard.

Answer (score 0):

Make your button look like the enter key:

[image]